# Error on ruby on rails test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to execute this test:

```
def test_create
 get :new    
 assert_template "admin/supplier/new"
 assert_difference 'Supplier.count' do
   post :create, :supplier => {:name => 'Juan', :province => 'provincia'}
   assert_response :redirect
   assert_redirected_to :action => 'index'      
 end
 assert_equal 'Supplier Juan was succesfully created.', flash[:notice]
end
```

The following line throws an error:

```
assert_template "admin/supplier/new"
```

Here's the error:

```
test_create(Admin::SupplierControllerTest) [supplier_controller_test.rb:25]:
expecting <"admin/supplier/new"> but rendering with <"">
```

but `<"admin/supplier/new">` doesn't work.

Comment: it's rendering `""` instead of what you expect. open your log/test.log and see what happens. read this http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: one option is to keep to the 'one assertion per test'.

Answer (score -1):

with some version, Rails stopped evaluating templates out of its "functional" tests.

You need to tell Rails to run the templates for this test. Either write a "view" test (which come with their own issues!).

The fix for RSpec is to add @render_views to your tests. I used the equivalent command for non-RSpec tests during my last project, so naturally I can't remember what it was now!

Comment: it should still assert the proper template!